# Objective C - Waiting for a method from another class to complete before continuing

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to display a loading indicator while I am waiting for a method in another class to return a value. The other class will use NSData to get data from a URL (for server login purposes).

I just want to know how I can stop my code in the main function to stop executing while i wait for the method in the other class to return a value. The main issue i am experiencing is that the indicator disappears because the code is continuing to run before I get a value.

My code is:

```
[self.view addSubview:loadingView];
loggedIn = [classB login:username password:password];
// More code

[loadingView removeFromSuperview];
```

I just want to know how i will be able to get around the indicator not being displayer. It will be displayed if i remove the following line:

```
[loadingView removeFromSuperview];
```

Comment: Stop thinking that way. You never, never, _never_ "stop your code" or "wait". _Communicate_ between parts of your code. Use delayed performance, if needed, to give the interface an opportunity to update.

Comment: See also [How to wait for an asynchronous method to be over?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6333133)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Send a notification](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/postNotificationName:object:) when the process is finished. [Add the controller](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSNotificationCenter/addObserver:selector:name:object:) with the `loadingView` as observer for that notification. Remove the `loadingView` when the controller receives the notification.

Edit: Added links to documentation.

Comment: Sorry I am quite new to IOS development. How would i go about ding something like this?

Comment: @AwaisHussain I have added links to the documentation.